# Mongo find by substring in any field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Is it possible to find objects in a collection by a certain substring, if this substring may be contained in any field of this collection.

For example, my substring is **"aa"**.
And I have 2 collections:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5788a3e4ffcf140b5955eead"),
    **"Address" : "aaBB",**
    "FirstName" : "First",
    "SecondName" : "Second"
} 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("7788a3e4fhcf140098725eead"),
    "Address" : "bb",
    "FirstName" : "First",
    **"SecondName" : "aaAA"**
}
```

So, what query should I use to get these 2 records?

Thank you

Comment: @chridam , I need search across all fields in a collection. But in this answer it is searched by the certain field A

Comment: Use `$or` together with the regex i.e. `db.collection.find({ "$or": [ { "Address": /aa/ }, { "SecondName": /aa/ } ] })`

Comment: @SSDMS Sounds ideal, will reopen but cannot close again as vote to do so will be expended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution for my case:

```
db.getCollection('ContractAnswers').find({$where:"JSON.stringify(this).indexOf('aa')!=-1"})
```

Comment: My girl! it works..